# How to implement an isolated connection matrix

Tags: relay, isolation, current-source

I need to implement a circuit for a researcher, which looks a little bit like this:

[image: Isolated current drivers]

**Description of the circuit:**

There are two or more fully isolated biphasic current drivers, and N output pins. Any of the current drivers can connect to any of the outputs. On the diagram I have represented this part of the circuit as 4 plugs on flying leads which can connect to any of the 8 sockets. The connections will need to be changed dynamically and arbitrarily, perhaps up to 100Hz. The output voltage may need to be as high as ±80v, but the current will no more than 10mA.

**What's my problem?**

I have no problems implementing the fully isolated current drivers. What I'm not sure about is connecting the drivers to the outputs.

**What have I thought of so far?**

The only way I can imagine doing this is to use a 4x8 matrix of relays (or solid state relays). I could probably do this, but I'm aware that in the course of the project they're going to want to expand the number of outputs to 64, and the number of drivers to 4 or 8. This is going to mean a circuit containing 1024 relays!

Is there some alternative way I could approach this problem. I am open to any kind of suggestions.

Comment: This is traditionally the realm of a crosspoint (AKA crossbar) switch.  However, all the ones available that I'm aware of are Low Voltage. 80 V is going to be hard.  You can see why implementing this is one substrate is easily done.  Hope this helps you in your search.  If you implement something more hierarchical (and incur more inserted impedance) you get a "minimum spanning non-blocking switch" with far fewer components.

Answer (score 1):

Four HP E1466A/E1467A (4x64/8x32 relay matrix switch) will do the trick for 8 drivers and 64 outputs.

Comment: Holy moly! That's a beast. I was hoping to avoid this kind of massive and expensive equipment.

Comment: There is also some hardware from NI: NI PXI-2532 but NI-PXI may be much more expensive than HP. You can find E1466A on eBay for $500.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a analog demultiplexer IC.
Something like this : http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4051-ep.pdf

But when it comes to 64 outputs, you could use the knowledge of 'divide and 
conquer' algorithm into practice. 
You could do something like this with 8to1 analog demultiplexer, then you
only need 9 chips for 64 ports. or if you use 16to1 demultiplexer there only
you need 4 of them and another one 4to1 demultiplexer.

[image: the basic idea]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. However that TI chip cannot accept the high voltages I need for my application.