# Routing Current to Many Individual Channels

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay, routing, matrix, power-engineering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement an isolated connection matrix](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42802/how-to-implement-an-isolated-connection-matrix)

I need to put current on up to 30 lines; one at a time.  What kind of electronics solutions are there to this kind of problem.

I can't drive it directly with a microcontroller because I need 28 VDC.

Response to Comments:

- 28 VDC
- Less than an amp of current
- Only needs to switch as fast as a human can press a button. maybe a few times per second max.

Comment: Is that 28 V AC or DC? How much current? How fast do you have to switch? (There's a huge difference between 100 times per second and once a day)

Comment: Hah. I'm working on a similar problem!

Answer (score 0):

[Driver for NMOS](http://www.linear.com/product/LT1161) to implement a high side switch, is the best I could find.